# BYTSE2 - spoj: Please suggest what i might be doing wrong?

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-programming

```
//BYTESE2

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

bool compare(const ll &i, const ll &j)
{
return (abs(i) < abs(j));
} 

int main()
{
std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
int t,n;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    vector <ll> v;
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0)
    {
        cout<<"0\n";
        continue;
    }
    ll start, end, i, j;
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>start>>end;
        v.push_back(start * 1);
        v.push_back(end * -1);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    int c=0, max=0;
    vector <ll>::iterator it = v.begin();
    while(it != v.end())
    {
        if(*it > 0)
            c++;
        else
            c--;
        if(max < c)
            max = c;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<max<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Using a variable to store current no. of dancers in the hall. For every exit I'm subtracting from the variable. I tried on some test cases, it is working fine. 
But on submission, it says WRONG ANSWER!

I had tried so many ways to do this question but in vain!
Please suggest what I might be doing wrong!
Link to the question: http://www.spoj.com/problems/BYTESE2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems perfectly fine to me. Liked the approach as well of saving the start time as positive and end time as negative, but it seems that in the given problem the time is not always positive, that is, that Hagrid might have started recording time from some negative number, so in that case both starting and ending time could be negative, which would give a wrong answer with this approach. So, you will have to use some extra memory to store whether it is the starting or ending time. I edited your code to the following and it got accepted.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool compare(const pair<int, bool> &i, const pair<int, bool> &j)
{
    return (i.first < j.first);
} 

int main()
{
    int t,n;
    vector <pair<int, bool> > v;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>n;

        int start, end, i, j;
        j=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>start>>end;
            pair <int, bool> p1 (start, true);
            pair<int, bool> p2 (end, false);
            v.push_back(p1);
            v.push_back(p2);
        }
        sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
        int c=0, max=0;
        vector <pair<int, bool> >::iterator it = v.begin();
        while(it != v.end())
        {
            if((*it).second)
                c++;
            else
                c--;
            if(max < c)
                max = c;
            it++;
        }
        cout<<max<<endl;
        v.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh alright! Ya constraint on start and end is not properly defined.
Thanks!